# Blue box next to header (tikz)

Tags: tikz-pgf, header-footer, fancyhdr

I would like to draw a blue box next to the header but the blue box should be in the margin and not be part of the header it self. In the real document the margins are set with `geometry`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{color}

%\usepackage\[a4paper,%showframe,
%left= 2.5cm,                   % linker Rand
%right= 1.99cm,             % rechter Rand
%top= 2.5cm,                % oberer Rand
%bottom= 2cm,           % unterer Rand
%\] 
%{geometry}

\newsavebox\myLogoBox
\savebox\myLogoBox{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill\[fill=blue\] (1mm,2mm) rectangle +(2cm,7mm);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newcommand{\insertlogo}{\usebox{\myLogoBox}}%
\setlength\headheight{ 1.5  cm}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\insertlogo~\LARGE{\textbf{Lebenslauf}}}

\begin{document}
A
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the blue box inside a box of `0pt` width:

```
\lhead{\makebox[0pt][r]{\insertlogo~}\LARGE{\textbf{Lebenslauf}}}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{color}

\usepackage[a4paper,%showframe,
left= 2.5cm,                   % linker Rand
right= 1.99cm,             % rechter Rand
top= 2.5cm,                % oberer Rand
bottom= 2cm,           % unterer Rand
]
{geometry}

\newsavebox\myLogoBox
\savebox\myLogoBox{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[fill=blue] (1mm,2mm) rectangle +(2cm,7mm);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newcommand{\insertlogo}{\usebox{\myLogoBox}}%
\setlength\headheight{ 1.5  cm}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\makebox[0pt][r]{\insertlogo~}\LARGE\textbf{Lebenslauf}}

\begin{document}
A
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As an aside, one can directly draw the box using `tikzpagenodes` package.

Answer (score 1):

A variation on the Harish Kumar's [`answer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262644/3954), but now the box goes all the way from the left margin to a distance controlled by `\LogoSep` (default=`10pt`) from the text area:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[a4paper,%showframe,
left= 2.5cm,                   % linker Rand
right= 1.99cm,             % rechter Rand
top= 2.5cm,                % oberer Rand
bottom= 2cm,           % unterer Rand
]
{geometry}

% Separation between blue box and header
\newlength\LogoSep
\setlength\LogoSep{10pt}

\newsavebox\myLogoBox
\savebox\myLogoBox{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[fill=blue]
      let 
      \p1=(current page.west),
      \p2=(current page text area.west)
      in        
      (\x1,0mm) rectangle ++(\x2-\x1-\LogoSep,5mm);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newcommand{\insertlogo}{\usebox{\myLogoBox}}%
\setlength\headheight{1.5cm}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\makebox[0pt][r]{\insertlogo\hspace{\LogoSep}}\LARGE\textbf{Lebenslauf}}

\begin{document}
Test text
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

## Remarks

- Font switches such as `\LARGE` don't have arguments; use them as `{\LARGE text}` (the braces only if grouping is required) with a possible end of paragraph before leaving the group if required.
- I switched from the old `\lhead{...}` syntax to the modern `\fancyhead[L]{...}` syntax.